# Non-dev Marketer using Drupal 7 having trouble adding images to our homepage - only showing codes after uploading image into Media Browser

Tags: image, drupal

Image field is set to default. Image views in edit mode, just not on live site. I've tried using different image types (jpg, png) but not working.

Comment: Need more information about what's wrong and setup.

Comment: If I had to guess, check your text format.